# Javascript With Quote Causes Missing Argument In Blogger Template

Tags: javascript, xml, blogger

When I use the following code, it works fine:

```
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#article-sidebar-tabbed-archive-gadget').prepend('<nav></nav>');
      });
    </script>
```

However, if I use any kind of quotes, I get the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Example of the code used that causes the error:

```
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#article-sidebar-tabbed-archive-gadget').prepend('<nav><a href="#">Tags</a></nav>');
      });
    </script>
```

What causes the error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the code is inside an HTML/Javascript widget or inside a post, try like this:

```
    <script>
// <![CDATA[
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#article-sidebar-tabbed-archive-gadget').prepend('<nav><a href="#">Tags</a></nav>');
      });
// ]]>
    </script>
```

The reason is that Blogger has a way to mess some javascript coding unless you wrap it inside the CDATA.
A bit of trial an error for me to learn that.
Or maybe you just need to escape the all a element like this:

Anyway, I tested you code inside a new blogger post and it works fine. So, if I had to guess, the solutions I mention should work...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to escape the double quotes, try this:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#article-sidebar-tabbed-archive-gadget').prepend('<nav><a href=\"#\">Tags</a><nav>');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, but then Blogger rejects the template saying: "Error parsing XML, line 741, column 83: Open quote is expected for attribute "href" associated with an element type "a".".