# javascript code not working on blogger blog

Tags: javascript, blogger

I have blogger blog on which i want to show ad network ad code which is given below. I have added this javascript code to html widget but ad is not shown. I tried this same code on my wordpress blog where it is working fine.

```
    <div class="div11" id="b25f9e9f1760c4f82da91fda4c5669dce"></div>
<script>
    (function(d, w) {
        if (!w.adnet) {
            var s = d.createElement("script");
            s.type = "text/javascript";
            s.src = "//domain.com/loader.js";
            d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
            w.adnet = {host: '//domain.com'};
        }
    })(document, window);
</script>
```

Comment: Did you check errors in dev console and network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check my answer here: [Javascript With Quote Causes Missing Argument In Blogger Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57700489/javascript-with-quote-causes-missing-argument-in-blogger-template/57701592#57701592)

Probably it's the same issue causing the problem.

EDIT:

By Jared Smith's sugestion, here it is the your code with the changes and my reply to question linked above.

Unless the code is inside an HTML/Javascript widget or inside a post, try like this:

```
    <script>
// <![CDATA[
    (function(d, w) {
        if (!w.adnet) {
            var s = d.createElement("script");
            s.type = "text/javascript";
            s.src = "//domain.com/loader.js";
            d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
            w.adnet = {host: '//domain.com'};
        }
    })(document, window);
// ]]>
    </script>
```

The reason is that Blogger has a way to mess some javascript coding unless you wrap it inside the CDATA.

Comment: Since the question is not technically a duplicate it's fine to repost an answer here, but please post the *actual* code and not a link.